# Plot a data/Table from Mathematica using `pgfplots`

Tags: pgfplots, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I use `data1 = Table[]` in Mathematica 9 (M9) to generate a table of values. The thing is that when I read the data file, there's only one column! How can I plot this data file in LaTeX using `pgfplots`? Here's a ME

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
            \addplot table {TestTable.csv};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried `TestTable.txt` instead of .csv but without any success. 
TestTable.csv is generated in M9 with the following code

`Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "TestTable.csv", data1]`

where `data1` is defined earlier in M9 is some data e.g. numerical integration or similar. A smaller version of data1 in textform (i.e. TestTable.txt) looks like this

```
1.1
2.3
3.0
4.1
5.3
6.2
7.3
8.4
9.6
10.3
```

Comment: Can you show that data?

Comment: Try `\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y={<column name>}] {TestTable.csv};`

Comment: Yes it has `Dimensions[data1]` = `{1000}`  i.e. 1000 entries of pure numbers.

Comment: Should I change `column name`?

Comment: Can you post that data file so that we can download it?

Comment: It's nothing special really it's just a long (1000 entries) of numbers going basically from 1 to 1000. I've updated my OP with a smaller sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {TestTable.csv};
```

The y values are read from first column which has the index `0` (zeroth column).

Full code:

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}   %% why 1.5? pl. update
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
            %\addplot table {TestTable.csv};
            \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {TestTable.csv};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `TestTable.csv` has the following content:

```
1.1
2.3
3.0
4.1
5.3
6.2
7.3
8.4
9.6
10.3
```

Comment: I have `pgfplots` version 1.7, is that good enough?

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate The latest is `1.12`

Comment: Ok 1.7 sounded higher to me...

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate Well, it is bit confusing but look at it this way. `1.` is common to all versions. Then you count `3` as `1.3`, `4` as `1.4`.....`9` as `1.9` and then `10` as `1.10`.... `12` as `1.12`. Hope it is clear. Now the version is `12.1` so it will be `1.12.1`

Comment: Usually I don't have a problem with that but I was tired and so I was thinking in a physicist kind of way and simply counted 1.7 as larger than 1.12, which is true of course but that doesn't necessarily mean that it came after (i.e. it's newer).

Comment: @ShutupandCalculate I am a physicist too. :) But it is a convention adopted by Christian (the author of `pgfplots`).

Comment: Good to hear bro :)